# Disable the Button Generated by the CakePHP FormHelper

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I'm using a submit button generated by the CakePHP FormHelper. I would like to disable it using jQuery after the button is clicked. I tried using the normal "disabled" attribute but that didn't do anything.

How can I disable the button to prevent accidental form re-submissions?

Comment: `$('form').on('submit', function(){ $('input:submit', this).prop('disabled', true); return $('input:submit', this).prop('disabled') === true ? false : true;});`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy No need for the ternary. Just return `!$('input:submit', this).prop('disabled')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabling the form may be a better solution, to prevent submissions other than clicking the submit button, such as hitting enter in a text input.  You can set a `data-disabled` property on the form after the first submission, and prevent it on following submissions if it's set.

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
    var $form = $(this);

    if($form.attr('data-disabled') === true) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
    $form.attr('data-disabled', true);
});
```

Comment: Not that it matters, but why not use `.data()` instead?

Comment: No reason really, other than it's proprietary to jQuery and couples the implementation to jQuery even more than it is.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. You're already using jQuery, so what does it make a difference if it's proprietary to jQuery? And it doesn't matter if you use `.attr`, the attribute/value will be imported into `data` automatically no matter what. So it's not like it changes much. My point was why not take advantage of that? It's obviously not important, I was just wondering

Comment: That doesn't do anything when using the default CakePHP theme and FormHelper text boxes.

Answer (score 0):

you simply, add the submit button to your form and disable the submit button once it's clicked

```
<?php 
        echo $this->Form->input('submitButton', array(
        'id' => 'submit',
        'type' => 'submit',
        'label' => '',
        'onclick' => '$(#"submit").disabled = true;'
        ));
?>
```